# How to parse this Postgresql query into Django

Tags: django, postgresql

I have this Postgresql query:

```
select a.code from accounts a where a.code like '0077-7575%' or '0077-7575' like a.code||'%'
```

At django I am trying to do this:

```
q = Accounts.objects.filter(Q(code__startswith='0077-7575') | Q('0077-7575'__startswith=code))
```

The thing is I don't know and can't find a way to translate `'0077-7575' like a.code||'%'` into django since a.code is the field name... How can I solve this?

Comment: Doesnt work is too vague. Specify your issue. Any error? Wrong result like that

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I can't figure it out how to query `'0077-7575' like a.code||'%'` in Django, keeping in mind `a.code` is a field.

Comment: What was the result when you tried with the Django ORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am guessing correctly (that you are trying to check that your field is contained inside `'0077-7575'`, you could try something [written in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53787290/11014993).

Basically you would have to do smth like:

```
Accounts.objects \ 
  .annotate(querystring=Value('0077-7575', output_field=CharField())) \ 
  .filter(querystring__contains=F('code'))
```